# Replacing one letter with an image without destroying text flow with Jquery

Tags: jquery, graphical-logo, letter

**Object:** I have a header title from which I want to replace only one letter with an image logo.

**Problem:** After working with `<span>` it somehow destroys my design, I means it breaks lines, does not properly replace the letter but appears somewhere else. I know it is the positioning but a lot of approaches went straight down the drain. Anyone has an idea?

My script, quite basic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
            $('#logo span').fadeOut(7000);
            $('#logo span 2').fadeIn(2000);
      });
    </script>
```

My css:

```
 <style>
     #logo .span 2 {display:none}
    </style>
```

My html:

```
<!-- Header & Call to Action Area -->
<div id="logo"><a href="index.html">Mundo<img class="logo" src="pictures/logos/logo_mundo_krone_header.png" width="100" height="56" alt="logo kundo gourmet puerto varas,restaurant puerto varas,puerto varas lujo,extravagante puerto varas" /><br />Gour<span><span class="2"><img src="pictures/logos/logo_mundo_krone_header.png" width="100" height="56" /></span>m</span>et</a></div>
```

Comment: Could you please make a mockup on jsFiddle so we can more clearly see how you've approached this design flaw? I say flaw, because this sounds like a pound-my-toes-with-a-hammer type of scenario.

Comment: Hahahaha, yeah, I see that! Right, I tried that before but Fidlle does not serve. I guess that is because it works with pictures. But I am not quite sure. Pretty new to me this fiddle thing. I guess it has to do with positioning and has to be solved by css. But I just ran out of ideas! Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QRgTH/1/.

Comment: So, in the above fiddle, based on the position of the image, what is it you want to change? what 'breaks' so to speak? Obviously you want to insert the image in the middle of the text, or you wouldn't have. So *what exactly is the issue*?

Comment: Well, inside #logo span 2 I would like to fade in a picture while (crossfade) or after the span-tag (one letter only) fades out. Instead there is some weird behavior as span 2 instantly appears and fades out. It's weird, maybe I have been totally mislead!

Comment: Ahh...I see what's wrong here. you're saying `span 2`, literally. That is not a valid selector. What you need to do is to target the 2nd span, `$('#logo span:eq(1)')` is the correct selector.

Comment: Nothing is weird here. When a hidden element is faded in, the first thing that happens is that the element is shown with low opacity, so it goes immediately from not being displayed at all to occupying Wpx x Hpx; and you can't achieve a crossfade of two inline elements unless they have absolute/relative positioning such that one overlays the other exactly; and with a letter "m" occupying maybe 5px x 5px and an image occupying 100 x 56px a satisfactory visual effect will simply never happen. Even with improved HTML, CSS and javascript, I think the whole enterprise is conceptually flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh...I see what's wrong here. you're saying `span 2`, literally. That is not a valid selector. What you need to do is the following.

```
$('#logo span').eq(0).fadeOut(7000);
```

jQuery uses zero based indexing. here we're telling jQuery we want the first span to fade out.

```
$('#logo span').eq(1).fadeIn(2000);
```

Here we tell the 2nd span to fade in.

Generally speaking, these types of effects are combined together using `callback functions`.

```
$('#logo span').eq(0).fadeOut(7000, function(){
    //this is the callback function.
    //when the above fade completes, anything in here will run immediately after.
    $('#logo span').eq(1).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

*As a side note to anyone coming here in the future*

I've used jQuery's `.eq()` which is a sizzle selector, instead of jQuery's `:eq()` which is a jQuery selector. The reason being is that `sizzle selectors` can leverage the `querySelectorAll()` method, where pure `jQuery selectors` must traverse the DOM to find the element. While for the example above this probably isn't going to yield much in savings, on the whole if you do alot of traversing, this key note is important.

Comment: Man, thx a lot, I have been reading into that and I truly admit that this goes far beyond what I am capable of. I understand the beauty of the action now but how would I steer this with my css. What exactely does the eq(0) y eq(1) fetch from the css and how would I link this to the according html properly? Could you be a little clearer? Thx a lot for your help! really appreciated!

Comment: Okay, I had a spelling mistake in my css that I simply did not see. Thx a lot, incredible this technique. Learned one big thing! Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh, one question, I seem to get it: do i use just spans and this function targets the 2nd span in the acoording div. so this would mean i do not determine any other class in the css than a span class for the div. Well, I have to dive into that. It`s interesting.

Comment: In the above, we're searching for all pans within any element with an Id of `logo`. Each span has an `index value`, which is `0 based`. When we do `.eq(0)` that's the `first span found within that element`. Every incrementing number thereafter targets items succeeding. `.eq(1)` = the 2nd element, `.eq(2)` targets the third element. `.eq(3)` targets the foruth element, and so on. Always remember, these are `0 based selectors`.